# Where is SCALA_HOME on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, scala, ubuntu-12.04

I installed Scala on Ubuntu using the following

```
sudo apt-get install scala 

~$ which scala
/usr/bin/scala

~$ whereis scala
scala: /usr/bin/scala /usr/bin/X11/scala /usr/share/man/man1/scala.1.gz

~$ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.9.1 -- Copyright 2002-2011, LAMP/EPFL
```

My question is what should I put in the variable SCALA_HOME? /usr/bin ?

Comment: Try using `SCALA_HOME=/usr/share/java`. There's a possibility may need to symlink specific jars from that directory into `/usr/share/java/lib`. I think a cleaner and more reliable solution is installing scala from the tarball into a single directory.

Comment: 1. cd / 2. sudo find . -name scala-compiler*.jar 3. check if its available in which of the following location a. /usr/shar/java b. /usr/share/scala/lib/ 4. the directory where scala compiler jar is present is scala home

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of today I couldn't find an easy (and reliable) way of setting this.

As per Alex (in the comment above) installing from tarball (downloaded from scala-lang.org) into /location/of/scala/untar

Then I set `export SCALA_HOME=/location/of/scala/untar` in my `.bashrc` 
Everything works for now!

Comment: Remove the `$`. That symbol is used to actually call the value of the variable.

Answer (score 17):

Today I installed scala using "apt-get install scala" and confirmed the scala jar files are located in `/usr/share/java`

You should be able to set your `SCALA_HOME` to `/usr/share/java` and have it all work. I assume you want to use NetBeans so you will need to set SCALA_HOME in your .profile (or .bash_profile) rather than in your .bashrc because NetBeans won't see any variables set in your .bashrc unless you start it from the command line

```
$ find / -maxdepth 6 -iname \*scala\*jar 2> /dev/null
/usr/share/java/scala-dbc.jar
/usr/share/java/scala-partest.jar
/usr/share/java/scala-partest-2.9.1.jar
/usr/share/java/scala-dbc-2.9.1.jar
/usr/share/java/scalacheck.jar
/usr/share/java/scalap.jar
/usr/share/java/scala-library-2.9.1.jar
/usr/share/java/scala-compiler-2.9.1.jar
/usr/share/java/scala-library.jar
/usr/share/java/scalacheck-2.9.1.jar
/usr/share/java/scala-compiler.jar
/usr/share/java/scala-swing-2.9.1.jar
/usr/share/java/scalap-2.9.1.jar
/usr/share/java/scala-swing.jar
```

Answer (score 12):

For me its: `/usr/share/java/scala`
I determined this by doing
`dpkg -L scala`

This assumes you install scala using APT.

Comment: I only have `jline.jar` in that folder... On the other hand if you go one level up that is `/ust/share/java/` you get all the scala-related goodies.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and I did some digging
This takes into account that you are using sudo dpkg -i scala-2.11.4.deb; where the debian package has been downloaded

The SCALA_HOME should be /usr/share/scala; This is based on the following

- /usr/bin/scala is a symbolic link to /usr/share/scala/bin/scala
- /usr/bin/X11/scala is also a symbolic link to
  /usr/share/scala/bin/scala

The way I see the scala package is installed in /usr/share/scala which should be your SCALA_HOME

Comment: Scala from Ubuntu's repositories is nowhere to be found in the directories you have mentioned. I wonder who thought that it's funny to waste hours in searching for the damn location where this thing is installed instead of just using it?! -_-

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed Scala using

`$apt-get install scala`

then, after a successful install to see where it installed, run

```
which scala
```

If this command shows you the path to scala binaries.
Now run

```
pwd
```

Now export SCALA_HOME path into either of these environment files

> ~/.bashrc

or

> /etc/profile

```
export SCALA_HOME=<output of pwd>
```

Comment: I like your method better, but you might want to edit your answer to include cd to directory provided by `which scala` or better yet, just copy it and paste into the profile.

Answer (score 2):

I installed the untarred scala into `/usr/local/share` as it is on the scala download site.

In my `.bashrc`, I placed the following line:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/share/scala-2.11.8/bin:$PATH"
```

works great from terminal regardless of what directory I'm in.

Answer (score -2):

The SCALA_HOME should be the directory where you install scala from.
For example, the name of this directory may be scala-2.9.2.

Comment: I think the question was: for ubuntu, where might scala be in order that I can properly set SCALA_HOME.

Comment: OK. I think usually the 'sudo apt-get' command will install software under /opt or /usr/local. Maybe he can try to find scala-2.9.2 folder under those directories

Comment: @Seraph any package that touches either of those directories is by definition broken