# Scala home directory for creating Scala project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala, ubuntu, intellij-idea

I'm new to both Scala and IntelliJ. I've installed Scala plugin for IntelliJ

I've installed `Scala` in my Ubuntu system with

```
sudo apt-get install scala
```

When I try to create new scala project, I'm required to do **Scala Settings**.

[image: New Scala Project]

But the problem is **I couldn't find the the home directory for my Scala installation**.

What is the home directory for Scala in my ubuntu?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm with Glenn: I always install Java artifacts manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The plugin wants to know where the Scala libraries are installed (as it would want to know where the Java SDK is located for a Java module).  Note that for different Scala projects you might use different versions of Scala: 2.9.0 or 2.10.2, etc.  The dialog offers to download them or you can go to the Scala site and download them yourself.  For example, I downloaded scala-2.10.2.tgz from http://www.scala-lang.org/download/ and expanded it in /home/glenn/Applications/Scala/ to 
/home/glenn/Applications/Scala/scala-2.10.2/.  This latter path is what goes in the "Set Scala Home" field in the dialog.

Note that in my case this is preferable to using the apt-get installation of Scala because the API changes so much that I usually end up with different versions of Scala for different projects that I experiment with.

Follow the version links at http://www.scala-lang.org/download/all.html to the version page with the download for the docs.

Note that for me, IDEA wanted the docs to be in the "doc/scala-devel-docs" directory, whereas the downloaded docs decompressed to "scala-docs-2.10.2".  I made a link so that IDEA can find them.  My 2.10.2 directory looks like this, now.

```
scala-2.10.2
├── bin
├── doc
│   ├── scala-devel-docs -> scala-docs-2.10.2
│   ├── scaladoc
│   │   └── lib
│   ├── scala-docs-2.10.2
│   │   └── api
│   └── tools
│       ├── css
│       └── images
├── examples
│   ├── actors
│   ├── monads
│   ├── parsing
│   │   └── lambda
│   ├── tcpoly
│   │   └── monads
│   └── xml
│       └── phonebook
├── lib
├── man
│   └── man1
├── misc
│   └── scala-devel
│       └── plugins
└── src
```

Comment: +1 for the explanation. But, any idea about scala home directory when installing with `apt-get install scala` ??

Comment: I set up Scala manually and when I set Scala Home, I get **no /doc/scala-devel-docs/api**, Any idea, where can I get docs?

Comment: @TheKojuEffect IDEA and SBT (and sooner or later you will be dealing with SBT) both would like to have the Scala home as I described above.  Linux distributions have their own conventions for where they put things:  executables, libraries, and docs may end up in places that neither IDEA nor SBT can understand.  Moreover, the distros are slow to update Scala: 2.10 was out in Jan 04, but Ubuntu 13.04 had, and still has 2.9.2.

Comment: I downloaded `scala-docs-2.10.3.txz` but it doesn't contain `api` directory.

Comment: I moved all the docs into api directory. And seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 5):

Run

```
$ dpkg -L scala
```

It will show a list of files in that package. Search for `scalac`:

```
$ dpkg -L scala | grep scalac
```

It will be something like `/usr/share/scala/bin/scalac`. Strip off `/bin/scalac` part and you will get Scala home: `/usr/share/scala`.

**Update**

It seems that there is no dedicated Scala home in Ubuntu. `scala-library` package files are installed simply to `/usr/share/java`. I guess then that the most simple way to get proper Scala home is to download a tarball from http://scala-lang.org/, extract it somewhere and use extracted directory as Scala home.

Comment: `$ dpkg -L scala | grep scalac` gave two listings. `/usr/bin/scalac` and `/usr/share/man/man1/scalac.1.gz`

Comment: `/usr/share/scala` doesn't exists. :(

Comment: @TheKojuEffect, strange. I guess Scala packaging in Ubuntu differs from Arch more than I expected. Try grepping for `scala-compiler`, it should show something like `/usr/share/scala/lib/scala-compiler.jar`. Then apply the same name transformation.

Comment: @TheKojuEffect, I think that it is also possible that `scala` package is just an aggregator, and real files are installed with another package. You can try and apply this procedure for all dependencies of `scala` package (except obvious ones, like `java`). My `dpkg`-foo is not advanced enough to suggest exact commands, though :(

Comment: Grepping for `scala-compiler` gave me nothing. It may be ubuntu specific so I asked http://askubuntu.com/questions/358859/scala-home-directory in AskUbuntu. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @TheKojuEffect, see an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773293/where-is-scala-home-on-ubuntu. It seems that there is no dedicated Scala home in Ubuntu. I just have inspected official package `scala-library` and indeed, it puts all Scala libraries simply to `/usr/share/java`. I guess the most simple way for you is to download Scala installation tarball, extract it somewhere and use it as Scala home.

Comment: Thanks, I did the same thing as [Gleen's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19353616/1433665)